# Global SNP frequency database?

Tags: database, snp, allele-frequency

Is NCBI's [dbSNP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/) the most comprehensive database of SNP frequency?

I'd like to get the largest possible database of allele frequencies per 'population' or geographic region. For example, on average, which country has the highest number of As at rsNNNN?

So I'm looking for global coverage above all else.

Comment: Do you mean largest in terms of number of SNPs or most individuals? gnomAD is worth checking out https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/

Comment: Hi I agree with @sahwahn could you define the "per .... "

Comment: Looks like my answer was truncated! Sorry about that, I should have noticed.